# Add multiple products to cart one click - opencart

Tags: opencart

I am new in opencart, I want to add multiple product add to cart in one button click, Please guide me how to do that,

Comment: You can add plugins for that. [Visit Link](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=19279)

Comment: Thank for replay, I have installed this plugin, But it is not show checkbox in category page, See this link http://aranirice.com/demo/organic-rice/organic-boiled-rice, Now what can I do?